# How to send a notification to another user with notify-send

Tags: libnotify

[`notify-send`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libnotify-bin/notify-send.1.en.html) displays a notification box with the message that you want to display on your own machine.

Is there a way to use `notify-send` to send a notification message to another user and display the message on his machine?

Answer (score 8):

Bash can write to network sockets but can't listen/read. You could use [GNU Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) for this functionality.

A network notify-reader listening on port 10000 (no security):

```
#!/bin/bash

# no multiple connections: needs to improve
while true; do
    line="$(netcat -l -p 10000)"
    notify-send -- "Received Message" "$line"
done
```

And a corresponding client:

```
#!/bin/bash

host="$1"
echo "$@" >/dev/tcp/$host/10000
```

So you can send messages using

```
notify-sender.sh  your-host message
```